# KRUSKAL MINIMUM-SPANNING-TREE

Tags: java, xcode, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

I have a graph G(V,E), and i have to computes a MST (minimum spanning tree) containing **e** (edge belong E), if one exists.
I was thinking that I could use Kruskal algorithm inserting the arc **e** at the top of the list in order to make the algorithm choose this arc first and build the tree that includes **e**.
Is it the right way of reasoning?
If a MST including **e** doesn't exist is the arc ignored?

this is the java code I want to change:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class KrushkalMST {
    static class Edge {
        int source;
        int destination;
        int weight;

        public Edge(int source, int destination, int weight) {
            this.source = source;
            this.destination = destination;
            this.weight = weight;
        }
    }

    static class Graph {
        int vertices;
        ArrayList<Edge> allEdges = new ArrayList<>();

        Graph(int vertices) {
            this.vertices = vertices;
        }

        public void addEgde(int source, int destination, int weight) {
            Edge edge = new Edge(source, destination, weight);
            allEdges.add(edge); //add to total edges
        }

        public void kruskalMST(){
            PriorityQueue<Edge> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(allEdges.size(), Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.weight));

            //add all the edges to priority queue, //sort the edges on weights
            for (int i = 0; i <allEdges.size() ; i++) {
                pq.add(allEdges.get(i));
            }

            //create a parent []
            int [] parent = new int[vertices];

            //makeset
            makeSet(parent);

            ArrayList<Edge> mst = new ArrayList<>();

            //process vertices - 1 edges
            int index = 0;
            while(index<vertices-1){
                Edge edge = pq.remove();
                //check if adding this edge creates a cycle
                int x_set = find(parent, edge.source);
                int y_set = find(parent, edge.destination);

                if(x_set==y_set){
                    //ignore, will create cycle
                }else {
                    //add it to our final result
                    mst.add(edge);
                    index++;
                    union(parent,x_set,y_set);
                }
            }
            //print MST
            System.out.println("Minimum Spanning Tree: ");
            printGraph(mst);
        }

        public void makeSet(int [] parent){
            //Make set- creating a new element with a parent pointer to itself.
            for (int i = 0; i <vertices ; i++) {
                parent[i] = i;
            }
        }

        public int find(int [] parent, int vertex){
            //chain of parent pointers from x upwards through the tree
            // until an element is reached whose parent is itself
            if(parent[vertex]!=vertex)
                return find(parent, parent[vertex]);;
            return vertex;
        }

        public void union(int [] parent, int x, int y){
            int x_set_parent = find(parent, x);
            int y_set_parent = find(parent, y);
            //make x as parent of y
            parent[y_set_parent] = x_set_parent;
        }

        public void printGraph(ArrayList<Edge> edgeList){
            for (int i = 0; i <edgeList.size() ; i++) {
                Edge edge = edgeList.get(i);
                System.out.println("Edge-" + i + " source: " + edge.source +
                        " destination: " + edge.destination +
                        " weight: " + edge.weight);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int vertices = 6;
            Graph graph = new Graph(vertices);
            graph.addEgde(0, 1, 4);
            graph.addEgde(0, 2, 3);
            graph.addEgde(1, 2, 1);
            graph.addEgde(1, 3, 2);
            graph.addEgde(2, 3, 4);
            graph.addEgde(3, 4, 2);
            graph.addEgde(4, 5, 6);
            graph.kruskalMST();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on implementing Kruskal algorithm you are going to have to implement methods union and find. These methods are creating trees structure. First you initialize every node as root of its tree and than you are using union to merge them if it doesnt create a cycle.

So to answer your question just create your desired set by union find, before running the algorithm.